# Ck Editor Not Working on Server, but its working in local Machine asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, ckeditor.net

I installed Ckeditor plugin through asp.net mvc nuget package manager and added in bundle.config and layout. Its working well in local machine but not on Server(development). Getting Error Like "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"
can you please suggest me what i can do.
Thanks in Advance
[Here My Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW9Va.png)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the files exist on your local machine but are not included in your solution. So when you published your application on server, those didn't get copied there and you got a `404`. Include all the files of `ckEditor` to your solution and then re-publish.